# Forcing a call to constant version member function

Tags: c++, generics, constants

I need a way to force calling a constant version of member function. I'm trying to make it efficient as possible. Any good solutions?

EDIT: looking for a generic function

Comment: Make a reference to a const Type, or a pointer to a const Type.

Comment: Looking to make a generic function, can I avoid casting?

Comment: Why are you wanting to call the const version anyway?  I'm really not sure how much of a performance improvement this would have as I would expect the non const version of const method to be basically the same.

Comment: @Corbin, just to be more verbose. I can make no assumptions about the performance, just the state of the object when calling a non-const vs const function. And sometimes, only a const version function might be available even though the object has been declared non-const for some reason

Comment: @Corbin: Why haven't you made your first comment an answer?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Because I'm never sure what to post as a comment or an answer haha.  Also, I tend to doubt my C++ knowledge... Have made it an answer now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a reference to a const Type, or a pointer to a const Type.

You can do that in a fancy way, but at the end of the day, that's the only way.

Though really I don't see what the purpose of this is.  Seems like it's not worth the effort.

Also, I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by a generic function.  That needs some clarification, but if I understand correctly, you want to take a pointer/value/reference and pass it to a function and have it magically call a const method?  That would only work if polymorphism or at least a method of the same name (templating) could be used.

Answer (score 0):

It automatically calls the const or non-const version depending on which parameter is passed. You can only cast from const to non-const. That may seem silly, but it is the way of the world.

For instance, you could normally do this:

```
void function(char foo);
void function(int foo);

function(4);
```

The compiler will "decide for you" which one to call, you can make it explicit by doing

```
int x;
function((int)x);
function((char)x);
```

However there is no equivalent for explicitly passing an overloaded const version.

Of course, you can simply *only define* a const version, and parameters will simply be passed as const.

Comment: Sorry miscommunication, meant const-version for member function not standalone function

Comment: @user814628 I was illustrating the principle about how you can force a specific type to be used, but you can't use a cast TO type const because there is no way except only providing a const version. It doesn't matter if it's a member function or not. Sorry if I was unclear?

Comment: A key difference is that I can add "const" at the end of the function prototype to differentiate. Ex, void foo(int)const vs void foo(int)

Comment: I would want to call the const version of foo.

Comment: Yes, the only way to force it to call the const version is to only define the const version. I.e. only define void foo(const int) const, and don't defined void foo(int).

Comment: yea, so I'm looking for a efficient way to call the constant version foo given a non-const object

Comment: @user814628 Simply *only* define the constant version. That's the *only* way to do it (without wrapping it in a class or using another such hack). It is stupid that this is true, but it is.